# What does 'non cumulative overtime' mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

The side effect is mainly neutropenia which is reversible within 5 to 7 days, and non-cumulative overtime.

What does 'non-cumulative overtime' describe in this sentence? 'neutropenia' or the time?

Comment: It is probably a typo: a space missing from "over time" so "non-cumulative" refers to the disease.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  When quoting sentences or other text please (1) say where you found the text (2) who the author is and (3) give a link if possible.  That way we can answer better. Otherwise we have to guess.  P.S. always make sure you copy the text *exactly*. As @Weather Vane says, there seems to be a missing space and this changes the meaning. "overtime" is not the same as "over time".   I hope this helps!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is predicated on assuming a misprint is not such.

Comment: @Monica I'm so sorry for not giving a more detail description on my post. I am new here. I found the sentence on a medicine brochure and the sentence was written that way, with no space in 'overtime'. I had no idea when I was trying to translate the sentence. But, thank you very much, I understand the sentence now.

Comment: Thanks Weather Vane and Edwin

Answer (score 0):

> non-cumulative overtime

This is incorrect. It should be "over time"

Here is a paraphrase

The side effect is mainly neutropenia which is reversible within 5 to 7 days, and non-cumulative *as time passes*.

In other words, the neutropenia does not get worse as time passes. (but I am not a doctor so I can't vouch for this)